# geom_bar() + geom_text(): left align on axis, not on bar; and manipulate textcolor dynamically

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have a `ggplot2` barplot with `geom_text` labels, e.g. this:

```
df <-
  data.frame(ylabl = c("y_val: a", "y_val: b", "y_val: c", "y_val: d"),
             count = c(  2,   5,   8,  10),
             lab_2 = c("long label here", "short lbl", "medium label", "label medium length")) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(ylabl = fct_reorder(ylabl, count))


ggplot(data=df, aes(x=count, y=ylabl, label=lab_2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="stack") +
  geom_text(size=16, color="orange", hjust=0) +
  theme_classic()
```

This gives the following plot:
[image: sample plot: barplot with labels]

I would now like to adjust the position so the `geom_text()` elements are left-aligned on the axis (plus `nudge_x=2` etc.) rather than at the end of the bar. How can I achieve this?

Further, is there a way to change the text color of the labels when they have reached the end of the bar? E.g. for `y_val: a`'s label, `long label here`, approx. `lon` and 75% of the `g` in one color, the rest in another color; accordingly for the other labels, where applicable.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, just set the x position of the text with `aes`.
I have simplified the bars with a call to `geom_col`.
For multi-colour text you could use `ggtext`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

df <-
  data.frame(ylabl = c("y_val: a", "y_val: b", "y_val: c", "y_val: d"),
             count = c(  2,   5,   8,  10),
             lab_2 = c("long<span style='color:blue'> label here",
                       "short lbl",
                       "medium label",
                       "label medium length")) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(ylabl = fct_reorder(ylabl, count))


ggplot(df, aes(x=count, y=ylabl, label=lab_2)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_richtext(aes(x = 0.02),
                size=16,
                color="orange",
                hjust=0,
                fill = NA,
                label.colour = NA) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>